# Ruby MergeSort error with in_groups_of

Tags: ruby, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to do an iterative mergesort (I know there's already a sort method in Ruby). That being said this is what I've tried so far:

```
def merge_sort(array)
  return array unless array.size > 1

  merge_size = 2

  loop do
    offset = 0
    array.in_groups_of(merge_size) do |sub_array|
      subs = sub_array.in_groups_of(merge_size / 2)
      sub_array.size.times do |i|
        next if i + offset >= array.size
        if(subs[0].empty? || subs[0].first.nil?)
          array[i + offset] = subs[1].shift; next
        end
        if(subs[1].empty? || subs[1].first.nil?)
          array[i + offset] = subs[0].shift; next
        end

        array[i + offset] = (subs[0].first < subs[1].first) ? subs[0].shift : subs[1].shift
      end
      offset += sub_array.size
    end
    break if merge_size > array.size
    merge_size *= 2
  end
  array
end
```

When I run my program I get an error AFTER it enters all the objects:
`'block in merge_sort': undefined method 'in_groups_of' for #<Array:0x0000002c0db20> (NoMethodError)` Can someone tell me how to fix that? I read something like it might be apart of rails and not regular ruby. How can I fix that for Ruby WITHOUT rails?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is part of the `active_support` gem which is part of Rails. It is always helpful to look at the Ruby documentation http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/ and the Rails docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/

You can require the whole gem or just the part you need. For example `require 'active_support/core_ext/array'`

A simpler alternative might be to use the ruby `each_slice` method.